# Build CNN Model Using Keras

Tags: python, keras, theano, conv-neural-network

Hello I am new comer in Keras. I choose keras to Implement this paper : http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/TCDCN.html . I just change the input size to 48x48 then for the output I just need the 68 landmark coordinate. Here is my network:

```
def mtfl40New(size):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding='valid', input_shape=(3, size, size)))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(48, (3, 3), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.summary()
    #model.count_params()
    model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer="normal", input_shape=(576,)))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(136, kernel_initializer="normal"))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

However I get this error :
[image]
Anyone can help?
-Thank you-

Answer (score 2):

This is again an incompatibility between your input shape and the format how it is interpreted. You have set in your Keras configuration the image ordering to channels first, while the input shape has the channels at the end. To fix it simply replace this line:

```
model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding='valid', input_shape=(3, size, size)))
```

With:

```
model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding='valid', input_shape=(size, size, 3)))
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the solution. However I am still have a problem with that.
"ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 48, 48, 3) but got array with shape (2912L, 3L, 48L, 48L)"
How can I fix it?
-Thank you-

Comment: @herleeyandi That's a different problem, you should ask another question with complete information.